# Exercism: rna-transcription. Struggling with solution

Tags: javascript, for-loop, switch-statement, string-length

Trying to complete this Exercism javascript test but not working as I expected.

I'm quite new to switch statements so could be going wrong here, and perhaps using an array is unnecessary. Either way, my final `rnaString.join()` value is returning an empty string.

Also if there is a more concise way of going about it, I'd appreciate any pointers.

### Test

```
describe('toRna()', function() {
  it('transcribes all dna nucleotides to their rna complements', function() {
    expect(dnaTranscriber.toRna('ACGTGGTCTTAA'))
        .toEqual('UGCACCAGAAUU');
  });
});
```

### My answer

```
DnaTranscriber.prototype.toRna = function(dna) {

for (var i=0; i < dna.length; i++) {
      var rnaString = [];

      switch(dna) {
         case 'G':
            rnaString.push('C');
            break;
         case 'C':
            rnaString.push('G');
            break;
         case 'T':
            rnaString.push('A');
            break;
         case 'A':
            rnaString.push('U');
      }// end switch()

   }// end for loop()

   return rnaString.join()

}
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understand correct, your function should be like:

```
DnaTranscriber.prototype.toRna = function(dna) {
    var rnaString = [];
        for (var i=0; i < dna.length; i++) {
        switch(dna[i]) {//check character instead all string
            case 'G':
                rnaString.push('C');
                continue;
            case 'C':
                rnaString.push('G');
                continue;
            case 'T':
                rnaString.push('A');
                continue;
            case 'A':
                rnaString.push('U');
        }// end switch()
    }// end for loop()
    return rnaString.join('');
}
```

Comment: You're absolutely right. Completely forgot to specify the letter within the string. However, this returns only the final (or first... I can't tell) letter of the string, `'U'`. I need the entire string: `'UGCACCAGAAUU'`

Comment: Good idea (wasn't aware of the continue keyword), but still yields the same result!

Comment: Please see: https://jsfiddle.net/wqc32hfq/2/

Maybe you forgot change var rnaString = []; line? It should be under the loop, because inside a loop it will be reinitialize and you will get wrong result

Comment: That's the problem: I initalised my rnaString array within the loop, so every time it ran it reset it. Thanks for your help!